# C# WPF listview does not update

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

The column names are shown in the listview but the lines not.
So i think this part is correct:

```
List<string[]> list = gl.ReadCSV(fileNameBox.Text);

GridView gridView = new GridView();
listViewTable.View = gridView;
foreach (string st in list.First())
{
     gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
    {
        Header = st,
        DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(st)
    });
}
```

But i think something is missing here. Or not correct.

```
for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    listViewTable.Items.Add(new FHInfo(list[i][0], list[i][1], list[i][2], list[i][3], list[i][4], 
                    list[i][5], list[i][6], list[i][7], list[i][8], list[i][9], list[i][10], list[i][11], list[i][12]));
}
listViewTable.Items.Refresh();
```

Summary: the listview stays empty, only the column names are shown.
I mean, the listViewTable.Items.Add(...) adds everything (i can see that when i debug) bu nothing is shown in the GUI. (only the column names)
Thanks for help.

This is the FHInfo class:

```
class FHInfo
{
    private string building;
    private string floor;
    private string room;
    private string roomdesc;
    private string distributor;
    private string patchpanel;
    private string socket;
    private string switchFH;
    private string lineCard;
    private string port;
    private string vlan;
    private string device;
    private string gigabitAble;

    internal string Building { get => building; set => building = value; }
    internal string Floor { get => floor; set => floor = value; }
    internal string Room { get => room; set => room = value; }
    internal string Roomdesc { get => roomdesc; set => roomdesc = value; }
    internal string Distributor { get => distributor; set => distributor = value; }
    internal string Patchpanel { get => patchpanel; set => patchpanel = value; }
    internal string Socket { get => socket; set => socket = value; }
    internal string SwitchFH { get => switchFH; set => switchFH = value; }
    internal string LineCard { get => lineCard; set => lineCard = value; }
    internal string Port { get => port; set => port = value; }
    internal string Vlan { get => vlan; set => vlan = value; }
    internal string Device { get => device; set => device = value; }
    internal string GigabitAble { get => gigabitAble; set => gigabitAble = value; }

    public FHInfo(string building, string floor, string room, string roomdesc, string distributor, string patchpanel, string socket, string switchFH, string lineCard, string port, string vlan, string device, string gigabitAble)
    {
        this.building = building;
        this.floor = floor;
        this.room = room;
        this.roomdesc = roomdesc;
        this.distributor = distributor;
        this.patchpanel = patchpanel;
        this.socket = socket;
        this.switchFH = switchFH;
        this.lineCard = lineCard;
        this.port = port;
        this.vlan = vlan;
        this.device = device;
        this.gigabitAble = gigabitAble;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that list.Count > 1?

Comment: and issue is that lines are empty or listview is empty? Show us please FHFInfo class, this class should have properties, which names are exactly same as headers

Comment: I begin with 1 because in the first row (0) are the names of the columns. The lines are empty, when i debug, i can see, that the listview.Items.Add() adds everything but in the GUI the listview stays empty. (except the column names)

Comment: so could you please show as FHFInfo class?

Comment: did you tried to make your properites public?

Comment: are the properites names exactly same as headers from CSV file?

Comment: OMG it works :D

Comment: i had to make them public, thanks :3

Comment: No problem, i will add this as answer if you don't mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to have properites in class FHFInfo with names excatly the same as headers of your CSV file.
2. These properites have to be public.